# How to get the key of a CustomData in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to access the key of a CustomData, inside my list.

XML View:

```
<StandardListItem title="{NAME}" press="getSelectedId" type="Navigation">
   <customData>
     <core:CustomData key="{ID}"/>
   </customData>
</StandardListItem>
```

I can't simply pass the ID of the StandardListItem as my {ID} because is a integer, and for some reason, it does not allow. So I've created a customData for it.

So, whenever I press the List item I would like to get key of this item.
Here's an exemple of what I've tried to do to get it.

```
 getSelectedId: function(oSelected){      
        sap.m.MessageToast.show(oSelected.getSource().getKey());          
     }
```

The messageToast is just to see if I got the right value.

Unfortunately getKey() cannot be used after getSource, or oSelected

How can I get this key of my selected item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `oSelected.getSource().data("key")` should do it. (For readability it would be better to rename `oSelected` to `oEvent` and give the event handler a name indicating that it handles an event.)